# Add custom action (rejected, waiting, accepted) to webform submissions - Drupal 8

Tags: forms, symfony, drupal, webforms, drupal-webform

We want to add a custom action (rejected, waiting, accepted) to manage submissions of a webform form under drupal 8.

how can we do that?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Webform Application and Evaluation Demo within the Webform module.
You can customize the code to accept other form states and perform different actions like lock and unlock by extending a bit.